# call model class object in codeginiter helper file while using wanwizard datamapper

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, datamapper

While trying to access a user class object from codeigniter helper file, its throwing error like  `Class 'User' not found`. My code is something like 
    `$u = new User();
    $u->get();`
I am able to use this in library files but not in helper files. Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use model in helper you have to:

```
// Get a reference to the controller object
$CI = get_instance();

// You may need to load the model if it hasn't been pre-loaded
$CI->load->model('User');

// Call a function of the model
$CI->User->get();
```

hope it will help!

Comment: sorry this dint help me out